# How does this optocoupler work?

Tags: transistors, opto-isolator, common-emitter

I am working on an embedded system and unfortunately I have not got a proper schematic for checking power failure. However, I have a PCB for that so I drew a schematic based on the PCB.

I just roughly understand how the below schematic works but not sure 100 %. 
Especially, ***Anode is connected to emitter which is also connected to the ground in J1(Connector Pin 1). How does it work?***

Also, *R1 does not connect to anywhere in PCB.* It is just connected with a a bit long wire. **I just guess it has to go ground. Is that right?**

J2 is a relay and pin 3 and 4 are connected with a jumper that micro controller keep reading from if power is alive.

J1 is connected to a line from power supply,
U1-optocoupler (4N35),
J1 - 4 pins connector,
J2 - 2*2 relay

[image]

***If I get rid of the ground symbol, Does it make sense?***

Actual PCB looks like this
[image]

Thank,
J

Comment: I think your reverse engineering of the PCB is flawed. R1 must connect somewhere. What does the long wire connect to? Also, the anode of the LED will not connect to ground, unless this circuit uses a negative voltage. This seems unlikely though. Check your pinouts.

Comment: Take a multimeter and measure the resistance from R1 to ground. Maybe there is a middle layer that you don't see.

Comment: Maybe the board is just designed incorrectly which is why (1) you don't understand the reverse-engineered schematic and (2) the board has a "power failure" (whatever that means).

Comment: The PCB does not have a space for the optocoupler, so what the previous guy did is he just added the 4N35 and manually soldered between J1 and J2. I don't see any layers for that and slots.

Comment: It's a bit long story but anyhow as I took this project over, the previous guy had left already. I only see two pcbs that have same configuration that I drew. I don't see any connection from R1 in both pcbs. It is just hanging.

Comment: @Jin I don't think you understand. Are you familiar with multi-layer PCBs?

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean but I don't see any layers. It is just a double side pcb.

Comment: This optocoupler cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

The floating cathode of the opto-coupler LED makes no sense.  You got something wrong in tracing the board.  Either there is a trace underneath something you can't see, or the board has inner layers.

Unless this board has a negative supply, ground connected to the emitter and anode doesn't make any sense either.

Bottom line is your reverse-engineered schematic is wrong.  That needs to be fixed before you proceed.